# How do I add the two values together in this Ruby Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

I would like to add the values of this hash together, and output the total.

```
b = {"Mike"=>100, "Jim"=>20}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do as below

```
hash = {"Mike"=>100, "Jim"=>20}
hash.values.reduce(:+) # => 120
# or
hash.reduce(0) { |sum,(_, v)| sum + v } # => 120
```

Read this powerful method [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

Answer (score 0):

```
b.values.inject(:+)
```

will work.